# XML Grouping using XSLT without key

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, transform, grouping

I have this XML data

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
 <?xml-stylesheet href="class.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
 <université>
     <étudiant>
         <nom>Réjean Tremblay</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF8430" note="89" />
         <cours sigle="INF1030" note="69" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="75" />
    </étudiant>
    <étudiant>
         <nom>Martin Lambert</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF8430" note="75" />
         <cours sigle="INF1030" note="72" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="73" />
    </étudiant>
     <étudiant>
         <nom>Luc Alain</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF9430" note="39" />
         <cours sigle="INF1030" note="89" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="79" />
    </étudiant>
     <étudiant>
         <nom>Olive Saint-Amant</nom>
         <cours sigle="INF8430" note="91" />
         <cours sigle="INF1230" note="99" />
    </étudiant>
 </université>
```

I need to get the average grade (note) for each cours (cours) grouped by nom (name) and cours (course).

THis is

this is the xsl transform I have so far but everything I tried to add a select-value-of-group I get error messages that transform failed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>

  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th>Étudiant</th>
      <th>Moyenne</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="université/étudiant">
        <xsl:sort select="nom"/>
         <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="nom"/></td>

            <td><xsl:value-of select="cours/@note"/></td>
        </tr>   
    </xsl:for-each> 

  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output should be something like this

[image]

Comment: "*I need to get the average grade (note) for each cours (cours) grouped by nom (name) and cours (course).*" That's not at all what your output shows. You show an average for each student, which requires no grouping, since each student's grades are already grouped inside  the  `étudiant` element.

Comment: What is the significance of the phrase "without key" in your title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change:

```
<xsl:value-of select="cours/@note"/>
```

to:

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(cours/@note) div count(cours)"/>
```

you will get the average grade for each student.

Comment: Yes that worked. I was so close. I had tried something but never thought to actually add the sum and div directly to the select. I really appreciate it. Thanks.